# Full CSS3 "special" tabs

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if this kind of tabs could be made fully in CSS or am I going to need images?

[image]

Regards!

Comment: Yes, it can be done in CSS, there are many example of CSS triangles, shapes etc.

Comment: http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/WvjyNM

Comment: @Paulie_D This is just awesome, this fits perfectly my need, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can by using:

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 25% 50%, 0% 0%);
clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 25% 50%, 0% 0%);
```

They are called 'Chevron'.